# how to create onclick for a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, href

i have a `div` for which i set value dynamically during run time, if there is value than i have enable or create a link which will have `onclick` method where i will call a `javascript` method.

how to do this in `jquery` or `javascript`?

I set value to a `div` like the following,

```
document.getElementById('attachmentName').innerHTML=projectInforamtionMap.Cim_AttachmentNames;
```

this the div :

```
<tr>
  <td align="left"><div id="attachmentName"> </div></td>
</tr>
```

Kindly help me to find and fix.

Best Regards

Comment: Use .setAttribute in javascript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set a onclick function:

```
document.getElementById('attachmentName').onclick = function() {};
```

Comment: i just put alert but it is not working for all the answer given

Comment: Can you make a sample on JsFiddle?

Comment: You did a mistake here: `document.getElementById('attachmentName")`. You use `quote` to start and `double quote` to end. If you fix it, your example will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that your function are previously define like this

```
function foo(){alert('function call');}
```

After adding innerHTML

In Javascript

```
document.getElementById('attachmentName').setAttribute('onclick','foo()');
```

In Jquery

```
$("#attachmentName").attr('onclick','foo()');
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several alternatives

JavaScript:

```
// var elem = document.getElementById('attachmentName');
elem.onclick = function() {};
elem.setAttribute('onclick','foo()');
elem.addEventListener('onclick', foo, false); // The most appropiate way
```

jQuery:

```
// var elem = $('#attachmentName');
elem.click(foo);
elem.on('click', foo);
$('body').on('click', elem, foo);
```

Between the 3 jQuery alternatives, the last is the best one. The reason is due to the fact that you are attaching an event just the body element. In this case, it does not matter but in other cases, you are probably willing to attach the same event to a collection of elements, not just one.

Therefore, using this approach, the event is attached to the body but works for the elements clicked, instead of attaching the same event to every element, so it's more efficient :)

Comment: I came here looking for a way to add an `onclick` to an `a href`.  `.onclick = ` doesn't seem to work for `a href`s?  Your second option `setAttribute` works great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#attachmentName').click(function(){
     //do your stuff 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

jquery way:

```
$("#attachmentName").click(function() {
  some_js_method();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without inserting link in the div in following way

```
document.getElementById("attachmentName").onClick = function () {
                                                                  alert(1); // To test the click
                                                                 };
```

You can achieve it with the help of jQuery as well in the following way.

```
$("#attachmentName").click(function () 
                                        {
                                             alert(1);
                                        });
```

for this you have to include jQuery liabray on the page. refer jQuery.com

Still if you forecefully want to include the link in Div then following is the code for it

```
var link = $("<a>"+ $("#attachmentName").text() +"</a>");
$("#attachmentName").html($(link);
link.click(function () {
                          alert(1);
                        });
```

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

as i was converting a classical asp details page to a one-page ajaxified page, i converted the existing links in the page to get the details loaded in the DIV in the same page. i renamed the href tag to dtlLink and got that data in the jquery load() function.

detail.asp (server.urlencode is added and required here )

```
<a href=""#"" onclick=""javascript:LoadDetails(this)"" dtllink="detail.asp?x=" & Server.URLEncode(Request("x"))&y=" & Server.URLEncode(Request("y")) > link text </a>
```

parent.asp (it has some extra code for holdon.js spinner image, button enable/disable, results div show/hide)
Jquery

```
 function LoadDetails(href) {
 //get the hyperlink element's attribute and load it to the results div.
            var a_href = $(href).attr('dtllink');
            console.log(a_href);
            $('#divResults').html('');



            DisplayHoldOn();
            $('#divResults').load(a_href, function (response, status, xhr) {
                $('#divCriteria').hide();

                HoldOn.close();
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "There was an error: ";
                    $("#divResults").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                    $('#divCriteria').show();
                    $("#cmdSubmit").removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            });
        }
```